# Should "conda search my_package" list all versions of my_package installed in my environment?

Tags: conda

When I test Scipy from source using `python runtests.py` (where `runtests.py` is a test driver file in Scipy's source code), I got this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pythran'
```

But I checked pythran on my system, it seems to be there.

```
(base) zhfu@mac611225 scipy % conda search pythran
Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel
pythran                       0.9.11  py36h01dd064_3  pkgs/main
pythran                       0.9.11  py37h01dd064_3  pkgs/main
pythran                       0.9.11  py38h01dd064_3  pkgs/main
pythran                       0.9.11  py39h01dd064_3  pkgs/main
```

Does that mean `conda search pythran` does not provide the package on my system?

Answer (score 1):

`conda search` command searches for available packages (on channels). The command you are looking for is [`conda list`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/list.html).

```sh
conda list pythran

# packages in environment at /opt/miniconda3/envs/jupyter:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
```